# why wont jsx render firestore data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jsx

I'm trying to GET data from firestore and render it, in the most basic way possible. I can console.log the data, but as soon as I try to render it via JSX, it doesn't. Why is this?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {db} from '../../public/init-firebase'

export default function Todo() {

    const [todo, setTodo] =  useState()  
    const myArray = []

    //retrive data from firestore and push to empty array
    function getData(){
        db.collection('Todos')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id +'pushed to myArray')
                myArray.push(doc.id)
            })
        })
       
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

      

    return (
        <>     
        <div>

            <h1>Data from firestore: </h1>

        {myArray.map((doc) => {
            <h1>{doc.id}</h1>
            console.log('hi')
        })}

        </div>
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change `myArray` to State like this:

`const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);`

Every change in myArray will re-render the component.
Then, to push items in the State do this:

```js
function getData(){
    db.collection('Todos')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id +'pushed to myArray')
            setMyArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, doc.id])
        })
    })       
}
```

You're just pushing the ID in `myArray`, so when to show try like this:

```js
{myArray.map((id) => {
    console.log('hi')
    return <h1 key={id}>{id}</h1>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely,

```js
        {myArray.map((doc) => {
            <h1>{doc.id}</h1>
            console.log('hi')
        })}
```

those are curly braces `{}`, not parenthesis `()`. This means that although `doc` exists, nothing is happening since you are just declaring `<h1>{doc.id}</h1>`. In order for it to render, you have to return something in the map function. Try this instead:

```js
        {myArray.map((doc) => {
            console.log('hi')
            return <h1>{doc.id}</h1>
        })}
```

Comment: this still doesn't render my data

Comment: Try combining it with yairmea's answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to force a "re-render" you will have to use the hooks that you defined

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

```
    function getData(){
        db.collection('Todos')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id +'pushed to myArray')
                myArray.push(doc.id)
            })
        })
// in case the request doesn't fail, and the array filled up with correct value using correct keys:
// i'd setState here, which will cause a re-render
       setTodo(myArray)
    }
```